# Why does __m128 cause alignment issues in a union with float x/y/z?

Tags: c, simd, sse, unions, memory-alignment

I've never actually ran into this problem before, at least not that I'm aware of... But I'm working on some SIMD vector optimizations in some of my code and I'm having some alignment issues.

Here's some minimal code that I've been able to reproduce the problem with, on MSVC (Visual Studio 2022):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

_declspec(align(16)) typedef union
{
    struct { float x, y, z; };

#if 0
    // This works:
    float v[4];
#else
    // This does not:
    __m128 v;
#endif
} vec;

typedef struct
{
    vec pos;
    vec vel;
    float radius;
} particle;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    particle *particles=malloc(sizeof(particle)*10);

    if(particles==NULL)
        return -1;

    // intentionally misalign the pointer
    ((uint8_t *)particles)+=3;

    printf("misalignment: %lld\n", (uintptr_t)particles%16);

    particles[0].pos=(vec){ 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
    particles[0].vel=(vec){ 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f };

    printf("pos: %f %f %f\nvel: %f %f %f\n",
           particles[0].pos.x, particles[0].pos.y, particles[0].pos.z,
           particles[0].vel.x, particles[0].vel.y, particles[0].vel.z);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why a union with float x/y/z and float[4] works with misaligned memory addresses, but a union with the float x/y/z and an `__m128` generates an access violation.
I get that the `__m128` type has some extra alignment specs on it, but the overall union size doesn't change and it's also 16 byte aligned anyway, so why does it matter?

I do understand the importance of memory alignment, but the extra weird part is that I added in an `aligned_malloc` to my code that's allocating the offending misaligned memory (I use a slab/zone memory allocator in my code) and it still continued to crash out with an access violation, which further adds to my hair loss.

Comment: Forgot, this is on vs2022 on windows 10.

Comment: If you have some information that you think is crucial or important, then please ***[edit]*** your question to include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alignof(your_union)` is 16 when it includes a `__m128` member, so compilers will use `movaps` or `movdqa` because you've promised them that the data is aligned. Otherwise `alignof(your_union)` is only 4 (inherited from `float`, so they'll use `movups` or `movdqu` which has no alignment requirement.

It's still alignment undefined behaviour, as `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` will tell you, since you're using an address that's not even aligned by 4.

https://godbolt.org/z/6GxebxT7r shows MSVC is using `movdqa` stores for your code, like `movdqa [rbx+19], xmm2` where RBX holds a malloc return value.  This is guaranteed to fault because `malloc` return values are aligned by `alignof(max_align_t)`, which is definitely an even number and usually 16 in x86-64.

Often MSVC will only use unaligned `movdqu` / `movups` loads/stores even when you use `_mm_store_ps`.  (But alignment-required intrinsics will let it fold the load into a memory source operand for non-AVX instructions like `addps xmm0, [rcx]`).

But apparently MSVC treats aggregates differently from deref of a `__m128*`.

So your type has `alignof(T) == 16`, and thus your code has alignment UB, so it can and does compile to asm that faults.

---

BTW, I wouldn't recommend using this union; especially not for function args / return values since being part of an aggregate can make the calling conventions treat it less efficiently.  (On MSVC you have to use `vectorcall` to get it passed in a register if it doesn't inline, but x86-64 System V passes vector args in vector regs normally, if they aren't part of a union.)

Use `__m128` vectors and write helper functions to get your data in/out as scalar.

Ideally don't use 1 SIMD vector to hold 1 geometry vector, that's kind of an anti-pattern since it leads to a lot of shuffling.  Better to have arrays of x, arrays of y, and arrays of z, so you can load 3 vectors of data and process 4 vectors in parallel with no shuffling.  (Struct-of-Arrays rather than Array-of-Structs).  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info especially https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/

Or if you really want to do it this way, you could still improve this.  Your `struct particle` is 36 bytes as you've defined it, with two wasted 32-bit float slots.  It could have been 32 bytes: `xyz, radius, xyz, zeroed padding`, so you could have `alignof(particle) == 16` without increasing the size to 48 bytes, to be able to load it efficiently (never spanning cache-line boundaries).  The radius would get loaded as high garbage along `_mm_load_ps(&particle->pos_x)` which gets the x,y,z positions and whatever comes next.  You might sometimes have to use an extra instruction to zero out the high element, but probably most of the time you could be shuffling in ways that don't care about it.

Actually your `struct particle` is 48 bytes when you have a `__m128` member, since it inherits the `alignof(T)` from its `vec pos` and `vec vel` members, and `sizeof(T)` has to be a multiple of `alignof(T)` (so arrays work).

Comment: Yeah, in my actual code, I did have more elegant data packing to take better advantage of m128, I just didn't include it here because the problem persisted with or without it.
Sounds like this might be more effort than it's worth to do, with maybe an exception for a few select heavy hitter vector ops and just let the compiler do it's own thing with the basic math ops.
For what has been working with all the SIMD stuff I had in, it was only maybe a 3% increase in performance, not really critical or anything...

Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Seishuku: Ok, if your real struct had more members then the specific idea of packing it down to 32 bytes might not help.  That was just bonus advice, the first half of my answer is answering the actual question your [mcve] demos, which is nice and minimal, making it very easy for me to be able to answer without spending a lot of time wading through larger code.

Comment: @Seishuku:    Only getting a 3% speedup might be due to using SIMD in a way that's inherently inefficient, with one SIMD vector per geometry vector (AoS instead of SoA).  https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015 explains this nicely, that if you want significant SIMD speedups, you sometimes have to plan your data structures around your SIMD loops.  Especially on Intel CPUs, there's more FP math throughput than shuffle throughput.  Getting only a small speedup using SIMD the "wrong" way doesn't mean your code can't benefit.

Comment: Using AMD's uProf (I dev on AMD hardware mainly), it did appear that most of my vector SIMD functions were being passed mostly as is with the intrinsic being used, the compiler was only tossing in a movaps or movsd (I forget exactly what it was).

I might work in changes later on if I get around to it, but for a hobby project, it's not a huge deal.

Comment: @Seishuku: I didn't mean the compiler would have to invent instructions around your intrinsics, I meant that you'd have to use `_mm_shuffle_ps` and stuff like that as part of computing something about one particle.  But you wouldn't if you were computing the same thing about 4 particles at once.  Or if you use the scalar x,y,z part of the union, then compilers might waste instructions copying the whole 16-byte `__m128` or `float[4]` sometimes and maybe extra storing and reloading. And there's the wasted space in cache from having 16 bytes for each `vec`.